# Google Calendar Events from one Calendar to another using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar web client has a feature for it's events I'd like to access with Javascript.

IN the web client it's found when you click into 'Edit Event' on an existing event. In the 'Edit Event' page at the top there is a 'More Actions' drop down menu which will have an option to DUPLICATE an event or COPY the event.

I would rather be able to COPY the event since it's a much faster way of creating an exact copy to another calendar but the duplicate option can work just aswell with a few extra steps. But instead of in the web client I'd like to do it with Javascript.

Google has some examples of a similar action but this time they call it import. They don't, however, show an example using Javascript to copy/duplicate/import an existing event to another calendar. Here's the link to those examples:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import#request-body

I've searched pretty darn hard through the documentation for a way to do what that COPY TO action does but nothing seems to work that well.

So I guess my question would be: Does anyone know how to copy/duplicate/import an exiting event from one calendar to another? If so, could you please provide an example or link to where the methods are in the documentation.

Comment: Do a read of the event from the calendar that contains the original and then call import with the event that you retrieved from the get. You might need to add the current user as an attendee (by email). You can use any insert example and just replace insert with import.

Comment: Have you went through [Google Calendar API with JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986631/Google-Calendar-API-with-JavaScript)? You will find in the article some code samples on how you can manipulate your events and also links for the whole Google documentation for calendar concepts and its use cases.